# Evaluate for multiple checks for items in an array

Tags: javascript

I have 3 values whose value is to be compared to a key, like:

```
array=["test", "test1", "test2"];
array.find((ele)=>{
        return (ele === "test" || ele === "test1" || ele === "test2");
      });
```

I'm already doing this, however I wanted to check if there is better way to do this? I tried:

```
if (["test", "test1", "test2"].every(function(x){
     {return true;}
    }))
```

this does not work, any ideas?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Simplest code for array intersection in javascript](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1885557/simplest-code-for-array-intersection-in-javascript)

Comment: Are you trying to determine if all items in an array match a set of criteria or return the first item in an array that matches a set of criteria?

Comment: @RoboRobok; somewhat, but not completely, however it helped me for other usecase, thanks for pointing it out

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use `Array#some` with `Array#includes` to check if the first array contains any of the elements in the second.

```js
array=["test", "test1", "test2"];
if (["test", "test1", "test2"].some(x=>array.includes(x))){
  console.log("true");
}
```

Answer (score 1):

You could use [Array#Includes](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/includes) to check to check if you array has strings you are looking for!

**Demo:**

```js
let arr = ["test", "test1", "test2"];
if(arr.includes("test") || arr.includes("tes1") || arr.includes("test2")) {
  console.log(true);
}
```

You could also use [ArrayMap](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/map) and [startswith](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String/startsWith) function to look for strings that matches the required condition.

**Demo:**

```js
let arr = ["test", "test1", "test2"];

let checkArr = arr.map(x => x.startsWith('test')).join(',')
console.log(checkArr)
```

Answer (score 1):

How about using [`startsWith()`](https://www.w3schools.com/jsref/jsref_startswith.asp) ?

```js
let array = ["test","test1","test2"];
array.forEach(key => console.log(key.startsWith("test")));
```